# Why TypedArray.prototype.set() doesn't have Argument for endianess?

Tags: javascript

#### From the MDN manual, DataView.prototype.setInt16() Syntax is:

> DataView.prototype.setInt16(byteOffset, value [, littleEndian])

#### And From the MDN manual, DataView.prototype.setInt16() Syntax is:

> Int16Array.prototype.set(array[, offset]) 
> Int16Array.prototype.set(typedarray[, offset])

Here `littleEndian` arg is present in `dataview.setInt16()` for specifying the behavior of Endianess. But `Int16Array.prototype.set` func doesn't have any argument for specifying behavior of Endianess.

### As both the func are for binary view Why There is difference between them ??

### How Am i supposed to modify Endianess using `Int16Array.prototype.set` ??

Answer (score 0):

An `Int16Array` will *always* be in the native endianness of your system. So `set` has to set in the native endianness, which cannot be changed.

To `set` with a different endianness, you could use something like this:

```js
const create_data_view = typed_array => new DataView(
    typed_array.buffer,
    typed_array.byteOffset,
    typed_array.byteLength
);

const set_int16_with_endian = (typed_array, value, offset, little_endian = false) => {
    create_data_view(typed_array).setInt16(offset * typed_array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, value, little_endian);
}

const get_int16_with_endian = (typed_array, offset, little_endian = false) => {
    create_data_view(typed_array).getInt16(offset * typed_array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, little_endian);
}
```

But you have to now read with the same endianness using these helper functions.

For example, on my system,

```js
const a = new Int16Array([1, 2, 3]);
set_int16_with_endian(a, 5, 1, false);
console.log(a[1]);  // 1280, because the byte order was swapped
```

Comment: I know how to work out with the endianess. Don't you think making function in the typed Arrays protyotype for doing it. And simply use reverse func in it. 

So Again, My Question Was Why There is this difference And some internal func for doing it ??

Comment: @AnonymousUser264 Because it always uses the native endianness of the system. A `DataView` does not care about alignment or byte-order, so you can even write a `int16` 1 byte in, but an `Int16Array` is like a `short[]`, so you can only write in multiples of 2 bytes and in the native byte order.